# windows read the target of shortcut file in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, boost

How to read the target of shortcut file on windows. Tried using boost::read_symlink which throws exception saying "the file or directory is not a reparse point" message.

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{           
    try {
    boost::filesystem::path target = boost::filesystem::read_symlink("c:\\tmp\\blobstore_2.lnk");
    cout<<target.string();
    } catch(const boost::filesystem::filesystem_error& ex)
    {
        cout<<"in catch"<<ex.what(); // prints "the file or directory is not a reparse point"
    }

    std::ifstream smbConfStream("c:\\tmp\\sym_file_2.lnk");
    string ss((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(smbConfStream)),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    cout <<endl<<" ss: "<<ss; // From the output of the "ss" it looks like the information of the target is present inside ss along with other binary data. How to cleanly get the target out.

    int i;
    cin>>i;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you refering to Shortcut files, Symbolic Links Junction points etc.  They are different and handled diferently. (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A Windows .lnk file is not a symbolic link. It is a shortcut file. You use the [`IShellLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950.aspx) interface to manipulate it.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891.aspx) contains the following example demonstrating how to resolve a shortcut file.

```
// ResolveIt - Uses the Shell's IShellLink and IPersistFile interfaces 
//             to retrieve the path and description from an existing shortcut. 
//
// Returns the result of calling the member functions of the interfaces. 
//
// Parameters:
// hwnd         - A handle to the parent window. The Shell uses this window to 
//                display a dialog box if it needs to prompt the user for more 
//                information while resolving the link.
// lpszLinkFile - Address of a buffer that contains the path of the link,
//                including the file name.
// lpszPath     - Address of a buffer that receives the path of the link
//                target, including the file name.
// lpszDesc     - Address of a buffer that receives the description of the 
//                Shell link, stored in the Comment field of the link
//                properties.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "shobjidl.h"
#include "shlguid.h"
#include "strsafe.h"
                            
HRESULT ResolveIt(HWND hwnd, LPCSTR lpszLinkFile, LPWSTR lpszPath, int iPathBufferSize) 
{ 
    HRESULT hres; 
    IShellLink* psl; 
    WCHAR szGotPath[MAX_PATH]; 
    WCHAR szDescription[MAX_PATH]; 
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd; 
 
    *lpszPath = 0; // Assume failure 

    // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
    // has already been called. 
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl); 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
    { 
        IPersistFile* ppf; 
 
        // Get a pointer to the IPersistFile interface. 
        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void**)&ppf); 
        
        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
        { 
            WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH]; 
 
            // Ensure that the string is Unicode. 
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszLinkFile, -1, wsz, MAX_PATH); 
 
            // Add code here to check return value from MultiByteWideChar 
            // for success.
 
            // Load the shortcut. 
            hres = ppf->Load(wsz, STGM_READ); 
            
            if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
            { 
                // Resolve the link. 
                hres = psl->Resolve(hwnd, 0); 

                if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
                { 
                    // Get the path to the link target. 
                    hres = psl->GetPath(szGotPath, MAX_PATH, (WIN32_FIND_DATA*)&wfd, SLGP_SHORTPATH); 

                    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
                    { 
                        // Get the description of the target. 
                        hres = psl->GetDescription(szDescription, MAX_PATH); 

                        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
                        {
                            hres = StringCbCopy(lpszPath, iPathBufferSize, szGotPath);
                            if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
                            {
                                // Handle success
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Handle the error
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
            } 

            // Release the pointer to the IPersistFile interface. 
            ppf->Release(); 
        } 

        // Release the pointer to the IShellLink interface. 
        psl->Release(); 
    } 
    return hres; 
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hell of a time compiling this; I've got a set of the windows SDK headers and a set of the Visual Studio 10 headers from here https://github.com/nihon-tc/LFMtest/tree/master/header but I just get endless decipherable stacktraces from the Microsoft codebase. Is there additional headers I need just to open a stupid .lnk file?

Comment: @donald Surely it's your code that is wrong. You'll be printing an address rather than a C string, or something like that. The code here is reproduced from the msdn documentation. What made you think that this mistake was here before looking hard at your own code?

Answer (score 2):

Here's more compact version of David's code, with ATL (included with Visual Studio).

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define NOMINMAX
#include <ShObjIdl_core.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

#define CHECK( hr ) { const HRESULT __hr = ( hr ); if( FAILED( __hr ) ) return __hr; }

HRESULT resolveShortcutTarget( HWND wnd, const CString& lnk, CString& target )
{
    // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize has already been called. 
    CComPtr<IShellLink> psl;
    CHECK( psl.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_ShellLink, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER ) );

    // Get a pointer to the IPersistFile interface. 
    CComPtr<IPersistFile> ppf;
    CHECK( psl->QueryInterface( IID_PPV_ARGS( &ppf ) ) );

    // Load the shortcut. 
    CHECK( ppf->Load( lnk, STGM_READ ) );

    // Resolve the link. 
    CHECK( psl->Resolve( wnd, 0 ) );

    // Get the path to the link target. 
    const HRESULT hr = psl->GetPath( target.GetBufferSetLength( MAX_PATH ), MAX_PATH, nullptr, 0 );
    target.ReleaseBuffer();
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see what headers are needed to include.

Comment: @V.K. Updated. At least in VS2019, these 2 is enough to build the code.