# MFC-making lnk with custom icon

Tags: c++, mfc, icons, lnk

I'm using visual studio and would like to make 'lnk maker' which makes icon that lead user to website.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" http://google.com
```

I want to add my own icon on .lnk. 
lnk maker would be exe file and it include icon file.

How should I include icon file and export it on somewhere in user's folder on vs mfc.

there is some lnk maker solutions but they are not able to make lnk depend on user's os version or change icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IShellLink::SetIconLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761047(v=vs.85).aspx) allows setting an lnk file's icon. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986845/windows-read-the-target-of-shortcut-file-in-c) is a StackOverflow question where the answer shows how to open an existing lnk file and how to get/use the IShellLink interface.

Comment: my question was how to include icon file into mfc program.

Comment: Just add the icon to the program's resources/resource file. No need to extract it later, you can just reference the icon in your exe.