# Get target of a shortcut (.lnk)

Tags: c++, winapi

[EDIT - the title of this question was misleading so I've edited it and the question is bogus in any case. TL;DR - the zero byte files were being created by me, by mistake]. Feel free to zap this question or leave it here as a monument to my stupidity.

I want to get the target of a shortcut (.lnk) file. If the target does not exist, I want an empty string (or return S_FALSE, either way).

This code works, except when the target does not exist it creates an empty file where the target should have been.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? If I remove the call to `persistFile->Load()` then the `shellLink->GetPath()` function returns an empty string regardless of whether the target exists or not.

```
    HRESULT path_from_shortcut(std::wstring const &shortcut_filename, std::wstring &path)
    {
        HRESULT hr;
        
        ComPtr<IShellLinkW> shellLink;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink,
                                NULL,
                                CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                                IID_IShellLinkW,
                                reinterpret_cast<LPVOID *>(shellLink.GetAddressOf()));

        if(FAILED(hr)) {
            return hr;
        }

        ComPtr<IPersistFile> persistFile;
        hr = shellLink->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID *>(persistFile.GetAddressOf()));

        if(FAILED(hr)) {
            return hr;
        }

        // don't look for it if it's not there

        hr = shellLink->Resolve(null, SLR_NO_UI | SLR_NOUPDATE | SLR_NOSEARCH | SLR_NOTRACK | 0x00010000);

        if(FAILED(hr)) {
            return S_FALSE;
        }

        // persistFile->Load() creates a zero byte file at the target location if it doesn't exist

        hr = persistFile->Load(shortcut_filename.c_str(), STGM_READ);

        if(FAILED(hr)) {
            return S_FALSE;
        }

        wchar_t target_path[MAX_PATH * 4];
        hr = shellLink->GetPath(target_path, _countof(target_path), 0, SLGP_RAWPATH);

        if(FAILED(hr)) {
            return S_FALSE;
        }

        path = std::wstring(target_path);
        return S_OK;
    }
```

Comment: What does `0x00010000` in IShellLink::Resolve() do? I don't see any documentation for a flag for that method with that value.

Comment: It's actually redundant here, my bad, it's the timeout for searching for moved shortcut targets but in this case not used because SLR_NOSEARCH is specified. See SLR_NO_UI comment here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishelllinka-resolve

Comment: I've tried many (all?) combinations of flags to Resolve() but none of them prevented the creation of the empty file - I don't think they're relevant

Comment: Also worth noting that this must be possible because Windows Explorer shows you the shortcut details when you right click the shortcut and choose 'Properties'. It does not create the empty file if the target doesn't exist but it does show you the target path.

Comment: There's no point trying to Resolve a shortcut that hasn't had anything loaded into it. Don't call Resolve at all. Just call Load and then GetIDList.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks Raymond - if I call SHGetPathFromIDList on the resulting ITEMIDLIST it creates the empty file. Is there another way to get the path?

Comment: I should note that these shortcuts are coming from the recent files folder (appdata\microsoft\windows\recent items) - are these shortcuts special in some way?

Comment: OK, I'm officially an idiot - the zero byte files were being created by me in another part of the code (opening the file to get the file size with OPEN_ALWAYS without checking if the file exists beforehand). Apologies for the noise.

Comment: @CharlieSkilbeck `GetFileAttributes()` can get a file's size without have to open it first.

Comment: Mandatory ONT link: [Superstition: Why is GetFileAttributes the way old-timers test file existence?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071023-00/?p=24713)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this looking for an answer to the edited question, here's where I ended up:

```
HRESULT path_from_shortcut(std::wstring const &shortcut_filename, std::wstring &path)
{
    ComPtr<IShellLinkW> shellLink;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&shell_link));

    if(FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    ComPtr<IPersistFile> persistFile;
    hr = shellLink.As(&persistFile);

    if(FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    hr = persistFile->Load(shortcut_filename.c_str(), STGM_READ);

    if(FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    LPITEMIDLIST itemIdList{NULL};
    hr = shellLink->GetIDList(&itemIdList);

    if(FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    wchar target_path[MAX_PATH];

    hr = E_FAIL;

    if(SHGetPathFromIDList(itemIdList, target_path)) {
        path = std::wstring(target_path);
        hr = S_OK;
    }

    if(itemIdList != NULL) {
        CoTaskMemFree(itemIdList);
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Would using `std::filesystem::path` be easier or harder?

Comment: Not sure - does it have a function for resolving Windows shortcuts?

Comment: `std::filesystem` deals with filesystem objects. Shell Links aren't filesystem objects.

Comment: @IInspectable Correct. I just tried using the filesystem library. Yep, doesn't work. Turns out [.lnk files are not symlinks.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22988327/421178)